# clang++ not finding "iostream"

Tags: clang++

I followed the [guide](http://blog.johannesmp.com/2015/09/01/installing-clang-on-windows-pt2/)'s steps precisely except for the batch file step because I couldn't find `setgcc.bat`. I don't care about switching to the 32-bit version anyway.

I then performed `clang++ -v` and got:

```
clang version 3.8.0 (branches/release_38)
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin
```

I feel as the error is the target is `x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` because I don't have VS installed.
I then performed `g++ -v` and got:

```
Reading specs from \cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\lib\gcc-lib\i586-cygwin32\egcs-2.91.57\specs
gcc version egcs-2.91.57 19980901 (egcs-1.1 release)
```

I tried doing `g++ -c HelloWorld.cpp` and got an error that cygwin1.dll was missing, and then `cpp.exe` crashed.

How can I have `clang++ -c HelloWorld.cpp` run and give me an object file by not having the error below occur, and based on my details?

```
HelloWorld.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^
1 error generated.
```